# PDO Access and PHP COUNT field incorrect

Tags: php, pdo

I've a query in PHP that work well on localhost, but online I get error:

> exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[07002]: COUNT field incorrect: -3010 [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 5.

This is my query:

```
   $sql = "UPDATE 01Anagrafica 
                SET [01Anagrafica].[01DataOraUltimaModificaPassword] = ?, 
                    [01Anagrafica].[01NomeUtente] = ?, 
                    [01Anagrafica].[01Password] = ? 
                WHERE [01Anagrafica].[01ID] = ?";

   $vars = array("2018/04/05 12:00:00", "username", "passwordtest", "15");

   try {
        $s = $db->prepare($sql);
        $s->execute($vars);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e;
    }
```

Work well on localhost, I get error if I put online.

UPDATE: OK I've found the real problem but not the solution. Error is in `[01Anagrafica].[01DataOraUltimaModificaPassword] = ?` (It's a Date/Hours .MDB access field).

When I was using `$s->bindValue(':date', $date);` method, all is working. But now i've to use `?` prepared statement. But it doesn't work.

UPDATE 2: Found problem. It's only a typing error :(

Comment: Thats a wierd database,table and column naming convension you are using there

Comment: I'm connecting using PDO on a ACCESS.MDB database that convention names work in this way

Comment: @RiggsFolly you should see DB2 conventions ;)